# How to print node embed field in field collection

Tags: entities

In one of my content type i am using field collection(Title, Image, Body).
I am using node embed to embed node titles of certain content type in one of my content type.
The issue i am facing is that whenever i am embedding a node it is not showing title instead of it displays [[nid: 2]].

I am printing individual field collection item, to print body i am using

```
 $section_desc =  $field_section_content_info[$section_content_id]->field_section_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"];
```

i want node title to be displayed instead of [[nid: 2]].
what code should i write to display node title in field collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the raw value of the body field in your code. I guess the functionality of replacing [[nid: 2]] comes from a text filter?

Try rendering the field with field_view_field instead. In the example below the label is also hidden by defining $display and passing that variable along to field_view_field.

```
$display = array('label' => 'hidden');
$section_desc = field_view_field('field_collection', $field_section_content_info[$section_content_id], 'field_section_body', $display);
```

Comment: This code works fine but it shows label of section body which i have made hidden from manage display but still it shows.

Comment: I've updated the answer with code on how to hide the label.

Comment: Yes it is now working as expected but still showing blank space before the embedded node title like below.

"The node embed clearly works here    Demo page"

Comment: The blank space probably comes from your tpl file.

Comment: Thanks @Pontus Nilsson for your answers.
I used print render which shows blank space then i used drupal_render() which gives me the proper output.
Thanks once again for your answer which really saved my time.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct answer so that this thread will be closed.